# Add vertically centered horizontal line to fill block to right of text

Tags: css

In ASCII Art, I want something similar to the following:

```
My Section ------------------------------
```

It's just that I'd like that line to be done in CSS to fill the space automatically.  I don't want them to actually be hyphens.  I just want a visual line.

Comment: Is it important the line be comprised of selectable hyphens? In other words, would a (unselectable) background image that flows to the right of your text work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<h1 style="background-image:url(../images/middleline.jpg);"><span style="background-color:white;">My text</span></h1>
```

EDIT:

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542064/css-heading-while-using-line-height-to-shift-border/542329#542329).

Comment: Should add positioning elements for the background image based on ems (.5em, or a touch less to accommodate width of the line), so that it stays vertically centered regardless of how big the text gets.

Comment: Why ems? Just use background-position:center;background-repeat:repeat-x; and it should stay centered.

Comment: Why in the heck would you use an image for this. Just use an <HR> tag.

Comment: An hr is harder to center. Possible, yes, but you're going to get more wonkyness in display.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <div style='float:left'>My Section</div>
  <hr>
</html>
```

If you'd like the line centered vertically to the text, you could do this:

```
<html>
  <div style='float:left'>Hello &nbsp;</div>
  <hr style='position:relative;top:8px'>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick solution: make a span with width: 100% that's in the place where you want it and then set the border-bottom: 1px black solid;